# section sign special character (§) is not correctly extracting in dat file with non ascii value

Tags: linux, unix, sed, hive, special-characters

After extracting the file from hive table using beeline,
I am replacing the special character with section sign  `§` to get a final extract in dat format.

**Success scenario with manual replacement of `§` symbol.**

While manually replacing the `§` everything works fine and `§` symbol is available in the final extract in dat format.

```
sed -i "1s/^/H§1.1§1.1§ALL§${DT_PASSED}§${DT_PASSED}§1\n/" FileName.dat
```

**Failure scenario with Latin-1 value replacement.**

```
ds=`printf "\x$(printf %x 167)"`
sed -i "1s/^/H${ds}1.1${ds}1.1${ds}ALL${ds}${DT_PASSED}${ds}${DT_PASSED}${ds}1\n/" FileName.dat
```

I am getting `tab delimiter and NULL values` but `§` is not getting replaced in the FileName.dat file.
Any one came across the same issue before as this `§` file delimiter.
Any idea where I am doing wrong, Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of an input file and value of `${DT_PASSED`}? btw, could simplify to `ds="\xa7"`

Comment: `§` has no ASCII value as it is not an ASCII character. There are only 128 ASCII characters with codes 0 to 127 inclusive. `§` has code 167 in Latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1). Linux normally works in UTF-8,  which is neither ASCII nor Latin-1. In UTF-8 this character is encoded with a multi-byte sequence. And it is not a "double dollar", it's called "section sign".

Comment: It is generally a two-byte code `c2 a7`.